# Git book object storage example code

Tags: git

In [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#Object-Storage) section of the git book, there is ruby code that store git objects. However, the keys that it produces don't match with the ones produced by git hash-object command (explained at the beginning of the chapter)

```
$ echo 'what is up, doc?' | git hash-object --stdin
7108f7ecb345ee9d0084193f147cdad4d2998293
```

While the sample code in the chapter produces: `bd9dbf5aae1a3862dd1526723246b20206e5fc37`

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` automatically adds a `\n` to its output, so you're actually hashing the string `"what is up, doc?\n"`. You can suppress this by passing `-n` to `echo`:

```
echo -n 'what is up, doc?' | git hash-object --stdin
```

That gives the expected output.